# Creating a Node.js REST API using Firebase Cloud Functions, without Express?

Tags: node.js, firebase, rest, express, google-cloud-functions

I am working to create a serverless REST API via Firebase Cloud Functions, which seems to work well but the [examples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/authenticated-json-api) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) all seem to use a monolithic solution, since they use the Express framework and essentially map the root http request to the Express app, then let it handle the routing. I understand that this is because the Firebase Hosting platform does not have the ability to handle http verbs.

My expectation was that a serverless / FaaS approach would have a function for each endpoint, making for easy updates in future since there's no need to update the whole app, just that single service - i.e. a more functional approach.

What am I missing here? Why is the approach to use a single function to contain an express app? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of a serverless / Cloud Functions approach? And is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: You can certainly make a function for each endpoint, and express is not required.  I think this is fairly clear from the documentation.  You are just obliged to use Express-like request and response objects, no need to create an express app. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson - perhaps my mistake - I read "The event handler for an HTTP function listens for the onRequest() event, which supports routers and apps managed by the Express web framework." to mean that it *only* supports routers and apps managed by Express. Are there any example apps where the function-per-endpoint approach (i.e. without Express) is taken?

Comment: The documentation I linked to shows that example.  You just fill in the code in onRequest.  There is no need to route anything.

Comment: OK, I'll do more digging - couldn't immediately see how to distinguish between POST and GET (for example) on the same url, but I'll assume it's there somewhere :-)

Comment: I now see that it's in req.method, so should be able to use that - thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_express_request_and_response_objects) shows how to create an endpoint without the help of an Express app, router, or middleware:

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

All you have to do is arrange to send a response with `res.send(...)` or similar.